# how to create two columns with div and CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, multiple-columns

I realize that this topic was discussed many many times. However, none seem to apply to me. I am generating HTML page using ASP.NET MVC construct `HTML.DisplayFor()` which generates `<div class="display-label">Label</div> <div class="display-field">Value</div>` pair for every property. I am trying to display them as a column - each line would have a label and a value. I tried various combinations, the best I came is the following:

```
.display-label {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.display-field {
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Looks close to what I want; however, some fields have NULL value, in which case generated HTML is `<div class="display-field"></div>` In this situation next label is shown on the *same* line (where value would otherwise be).

I tried `clear` and `display` in various combinations - but none of them shows a label, a value and an empty block if the value is missing (for example, `clear` shifts all values up).

I am **sure** I am not the first one trying to solve this problem. But I couldn't find anything relevant; and my CSS skills are clearly insufficient. And yes, I know that I can write a custom DisplayFor template; but I was hoping that it wouldn't be necessary!

Comment: Generating that HTML is not the default behavior of `Html.DisplayFor` for any property type. I'd be willing to bet that some other developer added files to `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` or you're using some third-party library that's giving this behavior. That's where you should look.

Comment: You may be right; however, the code is pretty much from MVC scaffolding, and I cut and pasted from "View Source". And while there is a third-party library (AWS .NET toolkit), it is hard for me to imagine that it modifies DisplayFor behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got something that makes it work:

```
.display-field::after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Intuitively, I don't like it; so if somebody has a better solution, I'd love to use that one. But it works, and I don't have to mess with the template for a huge class

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="display-label">Label</div> <div class="display-field"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="display-label">Label</div> <div class="display-field">Value</div>
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Since HTML is generated by ASP.NET, I don't have a liberty to put the second line in between...